# Building fontconfig with freetype in non standard user home directories fails to find the freetype dependency

Tags: freetype2, fontconfig

I successfully built `freetype` with the following steps:

Download the file `freetype-2.7.1.tar.gz` from `http://www.freetype.org/download.html#stable`

The `2.7.1` version is a version that can be built into the GD library. The `2.8` and `2.8.1` version prevented the GD library from building.

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-bzip2
make
make install
```

I'm now trying to build `fontconfig` but it fails to find `freetype` in the following steps:

Download the file `fontconfig-2.12.91.tar.gz` from `https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release/`

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install 

checking for FREETYPE... no
configure: error: Package requirements (freetype2) were not met:
No package 'freetype2' found
```

I'm running Ubuntu `16.04`

Comment: You can also install freetype2 font with: sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev